# Custom WEPopover push controller

Tags: iphone, ios6, popup, popover, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm using the source code from WEPopover project to create a popup on iPhone. (https://github.com/werner77/WEPopover)

I try to push a view controller when I tap on a row in the uitableview displayed in the popup. The pushed view controller in iOS6 is displayed with the same view size as the popup. In iOS5 the new view controller is displayed correct on the whole screen size.

What might be the problem? Thanks in advance.

```
Task *task = [ar objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    TaskViewController *viewController =[[TaskViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.currentTask = task;

    viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, You need to push your ViewController from ViewController on which you are showing popover.